# jQuery Select2 dynamically add items defining "val" with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using jquery select2 and manually works fine! However, I want to dynamically add items by using this piece of code that I found in that [project's github page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

```
$("#e13").val("CA").trigger("change"); //works!
```

The above example works fine. But when I try to substitute "CA" with an equal variable it does not work:

```
var california = "CA";
$("#e13").val('"'+california+'"').trigger("change");// does not work
```

I have also prepared a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ngdsy25j/)

Thanks to TSmith and fernandosavio suggestion, single value worked. 
My actual goal though is a variable with multiple values:

```
var combo = "FL,CO,AZ";
var array = combo.split(",");
$("#e13").val(['"'+array+'"']).trigger("change"); //does not work
//$("#e13").val(["FL","CO","AZ"]).trigger("change"); //this WORKS!
```

That is also included in the above fiddle...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TSmith is right.

<kbd>[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngdsy25j/5/)</kbd> your fiddle updated.

`california` is already a string

`$("#e13").val(california).trigger("change");`

and `array` is already an array

`$("#e13").val(array).trigger("change");`

So, no need to put quotes on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have edited my question since what I am trying to achieve is a variable with multiple values (the second button in the "fiddle". Any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: But the second button is working now. Take a look in the link I've posted.

Comment: I must admit it does work! And I really spent too much time with it before I posted that question! Too many hours of work I guess! Thank you for your help and your time!

Comment: Just for the history and by looking back to my actual code, my mistake that caused all this mess was that my line was like this: $("#e13").val([array]).trigger("change"); instead of the proper way: $("#e13").val(array).trigger("change"); ...after too many hours of coding, I guess is time for me to get some rest :p

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all the quote and plus sign manipulation:

```
$("#e13").val(california).trigger("change");
```

Comment: I just tested it in the fiddle and worked! Apparently, I cannot say the same when I try to select multiple values (that's my actual goal). That is also included in the fiddle... Any suggestions?